# Android Mediaplayer declared as a variable

Tags: java, android

This is my first question. I'm a beginner.

Why does `Mediaplayer` need to be declared as a variable whereas the `MediaController` is declared as an object: `MediaController myMediaController = new MediaController(this)`?

Thanks

Comment: It is a class. It could be a variable (obj) of type Media player(class). Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media

Comment: Well, I've just tried declaring the MediaController as a variable first and I get the same results as the MediaPlayer. The tutorial i was following used two different ways to create an object . I just wondered why.